# What this plant is called

Tags: indoors

Any one knew the name of this indoor plant

[image]

Comment: One identification per question (so that we can evaluate every answer), and also try to include image, not link. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's Hypoestes phyllostachya, common name Polka dot plant, which used only to be available with pink markings on the leaves, but there are newer varieties such as White Splash with cream or white markings. I notice the leaf edges are rolled in some areas - this usually means it's getting too much sun, or it's in a dry atmosphere and needs higher humidity, or more watering. It does need bright light to maintain its variegation, but direct sunlight, other than for a short period, can cause problems. It also prefers higher humidity, so misting with water (especially when the heating's on in winter) is recommended. Water when the surface of the potting soil feels just about dry to the touch, water well, allowing it to drain down freely and empty any outer pot or tray after 30 minutes. https://www.thespruce.com/grow-hypoestes-phyllostachya-indoors-1902650

Comment: Thanks @Bamboo , ya i purchased this plant one day before opening this thread. It was placed outside with rest of plants so maybe this might be the reason. As i'm living in arabia so keeping this directly outside (even in shady area) heat will surely kill it. Yesterday night i added water as peat moss was feeling dry to touch. ** But i also noticed two of its leaves are bit dull anu idea what might be the reason **

Comment: Probably dried out too much (very hot air or insufficient  water or both) - you may find  those two  leaves get  worse and die off, but in  the sort of heat you're living with, indoors (presumably with aircon) is probably the best option for this plant. And misting at least once a day with tepid water...

Comment: yes it was almost dry , i added half litre water in pot, as this plant is indoor so i will add some water after 5 - 7 days ,i'm using rapitest moisture meter to check moisture level when it comes down to 1 or 2 then i add water to plants  . And thanks for advising on misting part will follow advice. i'm only keeping Aloe vera and Basil outside as they can easily handle soaring temperatures (which normally reaches 45 C) but now temperature is coming down .

Comment: @OmiPenguin those rapitest moisture metres are not very accurate.  They work on an electrical charge, if the soil is wet the charge should be strong, if it's dry the charge will be weak or not at all.Anything you added to the soil to help with drainage,like perlite or pumice, blocks this charge giving inaccurate readings.  They only work if you used only peat/coir and nothing else. You will probably be better off using your finger or a bamboo skewer.I prefer the bamboo. Insert in soil,check skewer in 30 mins, look at and feel it. If its wet don't water. If slightly moist or dry, you water

Comment: @GardenGems, Yes i did felt that repitest doesn't show correct readings all the time. Now i use both bamboo skewers and repitest meter. But most of the time i just feel the weight of pot if it is very light then it water time

Comment: @OmiPenguin Smart.  Very smart.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

There is an app called PlantNet that helps you find out the name of the plants, just take a picture of it and upload it to the app. https://identify.plantnet.org/

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, This app really works.